# Translate ckeditor text

Tags: ckeditor, translation

I need to **translate ckeditor text**, i saw a related post at

[How to use Google Translate with CKEditor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6434026/how-to-use-google-translate-with-ckeditor) but donot know how to implement.

Sorry I am an entry level programmer and need help!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please clarify how your question differs to the referenced question.  Also this is best a comment on the existing question, as you don't understand the solution proposed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use Google Translate with CKEditor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6434026/how-to-use-google-translate-with-ckeditor)